# How should mongoose's model.on('index', ...) be used?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In looking at the documentation for `MongooseJS` for `MongoDB/Node.js`, it appears that indexing may be specified on an object like so:

```
var MyModelSchema = new Schema({ name: String, index: true });
var MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', MyModelSchema);
MyModel.on('index', function()
{
    doStuff();
});
```

Per the documentation, Mongoose will call `ensureIndex()` upon startup unless the `"autoIndex"` option is explicitly set to false on the schema.  Once this is completed, the `'index'` event will be emitted on the model, which would trigger the callback.

My understanding is that this allows a user of a model to ensure that all indexing has been completed prior to use of a model.

I believe I heard mention of doing this via `app.configure`, although I'm not sure how this could be done.  Maybe there is another way to guarantee completion of this indexing operation prior to other parts of the application relying on the exported model?

How should this properly be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `'index'` event on your model is there to alert you to any errors that occurred in the model's `ensureIndex` calls.  You don't need to delay use of the model until the event fires.  That would get pretty messy.

Comment: one thing I am not clear on - does mongoose create the index in memory or in the MongoDB database?

Comment: @AlexMills Mongoose creates the index in the MongoDB database.

Comment: More specifically, Mongoose calls an 'ensureIndex' on the MongoDB database. Here is the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

Answer (score 1):

I found it useful to add the following to the area used to configure the project's mongoose settings.

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Model.on('index', function(err) {
  if (err) logger.error(err);
});
```